# Go: How to format this struct in a readable way?

Tags: go, string-formatting

I have a struct wrapping a `time.Time` object and would like to format it in a human readable way.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

type TimeStruct struct {
    t time.Time
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf("time: %v\n", t)          // nice

    ts := TimeStruct{t: t}
    fmt.Printf("time struct: %#v\n", ts) // ugly
}
```

([Play](https://play.golang.org/p/ZTYisZRAEN))

Why doesn't Go format the `t` field in `TimeStruct` the same as a plain `time.Time` object? Is there a simple way to format this in a readable way (without defining extra methods for it)?

Comment: Not without defining extra methods.

Comment: Could the downvoters please add constructive comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way for you to get the human readable time you want when using `%v` is to implement the Stringer interface.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

type TimeStruct struct {
    t time.Time
}
func (self TimeStruct) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("TimeStruct{time.Time: %v}", self.t)
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    ts := TimeStruct{t: t}
    // time struct: TimeStruct{time.Time: 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC}
    fmt.Printf("time struct: %v\n", ts)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, tried in Playground, but `%v` doesn't seem to care about the `String()` method.

Comment: @JakobBowyer Ah ok, my fault, I used `%#v` instead of `%v`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to embed the time, so its methods are available on your `TimeStruct` ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2jC-pk61lI)), eg

```
type TimeStruct struct {
    time.Time
}

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Printf("time: %v\n", t)

    ts := TimeStruct{Time: t}
    fmt.Printf("time struct: %v\n", ts)
}
```

Which prints

```
time: 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
time struct: 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Note the use of `%v` not `%#v` which will print the struct members.

Comment: Cool, didn't knew that technique! Unfortunately in my actual use case I have two `time.Time` fields within my struct, which would not work this way, would it?

Comment: @zero-divisor you could embed one which would mean only one would get displayed.  That might work for you, if not the `String()` method as @Jakob Bowyer suggested is the way to go.